# Windows 7 hybernation prevent on startup

Tags: windows-7, bios, boot

I have hybernate my windows7. Now I had an issue that, my enter key is not working. I can not delete my hybernate and the system is remain in a promp window for restore from hybernate or not. I can not log on my machine. Any solution.

Comment: Is the enter key the only key on the keyboard not working?  Have you tried to simply restart the system?

Comment: You can use **Control-m** instead of **Enter**.

Comment: no control+shift+enter+log key all are not working. but i can enter in     bios

Comment: Have you tried with another working keyboard?

Comment: no i dont have another keyboard. If i have a seperate keyboard it will work.. ;)

Comment: Why i got this a negative point. What is my mistake. If you dont know the answer, dont mark as negative question. This problem also has a solution. Dont blame. This is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the logon screen, keep pressed the power button and turn off the system. Then you can reboot it normally without being hybernated.
Though is *a bit rough*.

**UPDATE**

If your problem is really the `enter` key of your keyboard then your only option to verify that's only a keyboard issue is to plug another full-operating one.

Another try: even if you are on a laptop you should have the numpad `enter` key, try that one.

Comment: I can not go upto that stage. The system is not logon... bec, before that bootup stage, the system shows a prompt.... I can not do anything now...

Comment: @felix updated answer.

Comment: OK. I agree with your points. I would like to know if there is any option in BIOS to reset this hybernate options. So I am stand in this same issue. I thank you for your valuable suggestions..

Comment: @felix Hybernate state is not directly related with the BIOS nor is BIOS controllable.

Answer (score 1):

At log on screen of `windows-7`, there is a small icon on the top-left corner called `Ease of access`. You can click there and open `On-screen keyboard`, then use it instead of hardware keyboard to logon your computer. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to goto logon window.

Comment: I can not go upto that level. Bec, when the machine just starting, it asks with a promp window: restore hibernate data and delete the hybernate data. i can not click or enter there.. so the os is not booting...